# C# Store an object that has a dictionary as a field in SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, sqlite

I have a long list of crafted items with a reagents dictionary consisting of an int that is the id of a reagent and an int that is the quantity to use.

I have no idea how to store this list in tables.

```
public class CraftedItem : IEquatable<CraftedItem>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, int> ReagentsAndQuantities { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CraftedItem other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Recipe);
    public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

When I google it, I get lots of hits on how to use dictionaries but nothing on how to store a class which has a dictionary as a member. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you need another table (which store itemID, reagentID, and quantity)  ... (or serialization, but this is not recomended)

Comment: Don't use a dictionary as a field. If you want to use an ORM to map objects to tables, use proper objects and let the ORM map them correctly. `ReagentsAndQuantities ` looks like an attempt to emulate a many-to-many table. Use proper classes instead, eg use a Reagent class and perhaps an `Ingredient[]` property, where each Ingredient object contains a `Reagent` property, a `Quantity` and possibly other information as well.

Comment: You should have another entity, e.g. `ReagentQuantity`, that has its own ID plus `CraftedItemId`, `ReagentId` and `Quantity`. Each `CraftedItem` will then have a collection of `ReagentQuantity` objects related to it. The corresponding table would have 1:many relations with both the CraftedItem table and the Reagent table.

Comment: hehe it seems to bee wrong anyway ... as it seam like you have Recipe entity so CraftedItem should know nothing about how it was made because recipe is enogh 
.. so it should be just: Items, Recipes, RecipesReagents, Reagents ... also you should consider that Item can be Reagent so maybe one table for items should be enough

Comment: So I make another class called Materials with it's own Id, the item id, the id of each reagent and the quantity of each reagent and let EF work its magic to create tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to EF at all, but if you are just using normal ADO connections, you just need a separate table for your dictionary:

```
create table crafted_item (
  id int primary key not null,
  name text,
  recipe_id int
);

create table reagents_and_quantities (
  crafted_item_id int not null,
  reagent int not null,
  quantity int,
  constraint reagents_and_quantities_pk primary key (crafted_item_id, reagent)
);
```

The trick is then your CRUD which you use to populate the data.  I would think something as simple as this would work.  Assuming your CRUD GetAll method looks something like this:

```
  List<CraftedItem> results = new List<CraftedItem>();

  using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from crafted_item", conn))
  {
      using (NpgSqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
              CraftedItem foo = new CraftedItem();
              // populate the properties
              foo.ReagentsAndQuantities = new Dictionary<int, int>();
              results.Add(foo);
          }
          reader.Close();
      }
  }
```

Then, before you close your connection do another pass and dynamically bind the dictionary entries:

```
  using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from reagents_and_quantities", conn))
  {
      using (NpgSqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
              int craftedItem = reader.GetInt32(0);
            
              CraftedItem foo = results.Find(x => x.Id == craftedItem);
              if (foo != null)
              {
                  int reagent = reader.GetInt32(1);
                  int qty = reader.GetInt32(2);
                  foo.ReagentsAndQuantities[reagent] = qty;
              }
          }
          reader.Close();
      }
  }
```

I got a little lazy, but hopefully you get the idea.  Presumably your "GetAll" would have some form of where clause, so you would of course want to apply that to the reagents_and_quantities details to streamline.

Alternatively you could use a JSON datatype, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I used EF but your logic is perfect thanks.